# what is difference between this.width & $(this).width with fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am a bit confused about the usage of this and $(this).

Let's take the following example:

```
$('a.thmb')click( function() {
  var img_url = $("img",this).attr("src");
  $("#preview_img").attr( "src", img_url);
  $("#preview_img").load( function(){
    var pwidth = this.width;
    var pheight = this.height;
    //alert( $(this).width() ); // 0 <-- (1-1)
    //alert( this.width );     //720 <-- (1-2)
     $.fancybox({
         ....
         onStart: function(){
            //alert( $("#preview_img").width() ); // 0 <-- (2)
         },
         onComplete: function(){
            //alert( $("#preview_img").width() ); //720 <-- (3)
         }
     });
     //alert( $(this).width() ); //720 <-- (4)
  });
}
```

1. What is the difference between (1) ?
2. What is the difference between (2) and (3)?

---

I want to know question 2.
and the reason for difference (1-1) and (4)? just time?

Comment: Not sure why there is a difference in the first case but in this demo they are equal http://jsfiddle.net/GC3kS/ , so you should make some fiddle demo for better reproducing the problem.

Comment: could you post your actual demo here (such as in jsfiddle)? it looks weird to me (the first case), can't think of how they could be different.

Comment: it was just depend on system.

Comment: it was depend on system.I test in jsfiddle and all of value are not 0..... anyway..thanks T_T

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/koponyang/3GC3c/8/

Comment: in your example neither `this.width` or `$(this).width()` are inside the fancybox method but the `click` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is a variable that contains a reference to the image element with id "preview_img".

Passing `this` as an argument to jQuery ( `$(this)` ) creates a jQuery collection containing that element.

The `width` property of the image element (`this.width`) gives you the [**width**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-height) property of the image tag.

The jQuery [**width()**](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width) method gives you a computed width of the first element in the collection.

Comment: Beat me to it... Nice. (And not to mention with more detail.)

Comment: Could you try making a demo to show the case in which they return different values, here you see in this demo (we don't explicitly set the width via `width` property) they are equal http://jsfiddle.net/GC3kS/1/

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly a duplicate, but the gist is that the latter $(this) is JQuery object that calls on the "width" method of the jQuery object, while the former is simply a reference to a DOM element and you are getting the width attribute of that element.